# Ray Dashboard error in the browser "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: python, ray

When starting ray 1.2.0 in a jupyter notebook:

```
import ray
ray.init(num_cpus = 8)
```

The log says that the dashboard is available on:

```
2021-02-25 16:21:23,636 INFO services.py:1174 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265
```

But I get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in the browser.

Answer (score 6):

I've found the issue, I put the log on Debug mode with:

```
import ray
import logging
ray.init(num_cpus = 8, ignore_reinit_error=True, logging_level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This gives you the clue:

```
2021-02-25 16:21:23,641 DEBUG node.py:844 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to C:\tmp\ray\session_2021-02-25_16-21-22_158008_35392\logs
```

In the logs folder there is a dashboard.log with an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Dashboard build directory not found. If installing from source, please follow the additional steps required to build the dashboard(cd python/ray/new_dashboard/client && npm install && npm ci && npm run build): 'E:\\Development\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ray\\new_dashboard\\client\\build'
```

If you google this error you can find that is a known error in Windows.

https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/9114

Point:

[TODO] Dashboard doesn't work on Windows (related to Node incompatibilities)

Comment: The more accurate info would be that if you refer to the logs directory mentioned in the console *after* enabling debug logs as you stated, you will see the following warning message: `WARNING agent.py:331 -- The dashboard is currently disabled on windows. See https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/14026for more details`

Comment: I am running on macOS also have this error